# Billing Export when changing Billing Account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

we have Billing Export enabled.

If we change the billing account of the project hosting the target BigQuery dataset and enable billing export on the new billing account with the same BigQuery dataset as before, will there be any issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, every billing account has their own export. You will export the billing data to another dataset/tables. If you want a consolidated view, you must UNION ALL the data.